# Running Tasks generically

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, task, task-parallel-library

In my project I heavily make use of TPL, and I decide to design a generic way of producing tasks, instead of calling `new Task(Action);`, `new Task(Action<object>, object);` or `Task.Factory.StartNew(Action)` etc. explicitly. 
I will have a function like

```
void SpawnTask<A,B>( Action<A,B> action, A a, B b) { ... }
void SpawnTask<A,B,C>( Action<A,B,C> action, A a, B b, C c) { ... }
```

for creating and starting tasks.

Also I need to run a mandatory method after each task completed. Thus I have to wrap the actual method I want to run in another method like

```
void RuncTask(Action action)
{
  action();
  MandatoryMethod();
}
```

So far I come up with two different approaches.
First, using anonymous delegates:

```
void SpawnTask<A,B>(Action<A,B> action, A a, B b)
{
  A dummyA = a; // To localize the parameters.
  B dummyB = b;
  var methodDelegate = delegate { action(dummyA,dummyB); };
  var taskDelegate = delegate { RunTask(methodDelegate); };
  Task.Factory.StartNew( taskDelegate );
}

void RuncTask(Action action)
{
  action();
  MandatoryMethod();
}
```

Second, using tuple:

```
void SpawnTask<A,B>(Action<A,B> action, A a, B b)
{
  Tuple<Action<A,B>, A, B> tpl = Tuple.Create(action, a, b);
  Action<object> act = RunTask<A,B>;
  Task.Factory.StartNew( act, tpl );
}

void RuncTask<A,B>(object obj)
{
  var tpl = (Tuple<Action<A, B>, A, B>)param;
  tpl.Item1(tpl.Item2,tpl.Item3);
  MandatoryMethod();
}
```

I like the first one because, it is simpler. The second has casting, requires other generic `RunTask` methods to be implemented for different number of parameters. But I do not know if creating too much anonymous delegates can cause side effects.

Which one do you prefer? Why? Or what other solutions do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can always create an extension method on `Action<TA,TB>` ... and you should use continuations rather than wrapped method calls to implement the behavior of always performing another action when the task completes:

```
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static void RunTask<TA,TB>( Action<TA,TB> action, TA a, TB b )
    {
        Task newTask = new Task( () => action(a,b) );
        newTask.ContinueWith( MandatoryMethod );
        newTask.Start();
    }

    // if you need to support other signature (more parameters) you would need to
    // create additional overloads of RunTask with more generic parameters...
    public static void RunTask( Action action );
    public static void RunTask<TA>( Action<TA> action, TA a );
    // etc ...

    private static void MandatoryMethod( Task t ) { /* your continuation logic */ }
}
```

Now you can use this code as follows:

```
public void SomeMethod( int x, int y ) { ... }

// later...
Action<int,int> myAction = SomeMethod;
myAction.RunTask( 1, 2 );
```

Note that in the above implementation the continuation method (`MandatoryMethod`) will be executed asynchronously. If you desire synchronous execution (as is implemented in your example), you can use the overload of `ContinueWith` that takes a `TaskContinuationOptions` and pass in `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I mot quite sure what you are trying to accomplish with that. What advantage over directly using `Task` constructor or `Task.Factory` are you hoping to achieve?

As for a "mandatory method" that needs to execute after task finishes, look at continuations (e.g. `Task.ContinueWith`).

Comment: Maybe the question is not clear enough. The point is to create a task for all types of `void` methods generically.